# Comparing 2 excel workbooks and highlighting the differences

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro to compare 2 excel work books and then highlight the differences. I've looked to previous solutions and they helped a lot, however I still can't get this macro running. I've created 2 scripts to see which one works best.

**1.**

```
Sub CompareWorkbooks()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

strRangeToCheck = "A1:AK900"

'Get worksheets from the workbooks
Set wbkN = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\gebouwensep.xlsx")
Set Nieuweversie = wbkN.Worksheets("gebouwen")


Set wbkO = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\gebouwenaug.xlsx")
Set Oudeversie = wbkO.Worksheets("gebouwen")

If Nieuweversie <> Oudeversie Then
    Nieuweversie.Sheets(gebouwen).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If

End Sub
```

---

**2**

```
Sub CompareWorkbooks()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

Nlin = 1
Ncol = 1

'get worksheets from the workbooks
Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\gebouwensep.xlsx")
Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("gebouwen") 

Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\gebouwenaug.xlsx")
Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("gebouwen")

strRangeToCheck = "A1:AK900"

varSheetA = varSheetA.Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = varSheetB.Range(strRangeToCheck)

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If Not varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then

        Else
              Nieuweversie.Sheets(gebouwen).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is for code 2

Your main problem appears to be the following line:

```
Nieuweversie.Sheets(gebouwen).Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

You don't have variables set for "Nieuweversie" or "gebouwen". The former appears to be a remnant in code 2 left over from code 1, I'm assuming what you actually need this line to be is:

```
wbkA.Sheets("gebouwen").Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

I've tested this solution myself and it appears that fixing the worksheet reference causes the sub to run correctly

also - this isn't working in code 1 either due to the same line (I haven't checked the rest of the code though, there may be other issues). Your variable "Nieuwerversie" is a worksheet, and what you're doing is referring to a "Worksheet.Sheets" object, which is not a valid reference. If you just used

```
Nieuweversie.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Then this should fix the same line in code 1, although as I say I haven't tested the rest of the code